# How to Redirect to Login page while click on logout

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a application in asp .net 4.0.

Here when I am logged in to my application, go to inner pages, say "Manage Role" and copy the link and click on Logout button it displays my login page. Now i paste that link in another tab and expect it to display me the login page but it does not happen, it shows me Manage Role page.

So please give me some solution, how can i show login page in this case?

Comment: Destroy your session on logout click event.

Comment: What are you using to authorize and/or authenticate your users?

Comment: i used   <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="SecModule" loginUrl="Login.aspx" defaultUrl="Login.aspx" timeout="30"/>
    </authentication>

Answer (score 0):

you have to use session variables to check whether the user is logged in or not and thenin each of ur pages..in the page load event u have to check whether that session user variable is null or not if null den redirect it to login page

Answer (score 0):

Try using Session Destroy function available in ASP.Net
if you are using C#

try:

```
Session.Abandon();
```

If you want to remove a specific item from the session use (MSDN):

```
Session.Remove("YourItem");
```

**EDIT:** If you just want to clear a value you can do:

```
Session["YourItem"] = null;
```

If you want to clear all keys do:

```
Session.Clear();
```

And Then Check for Session Value on every page you want to restrict only with Session Access(for Logged In User).

Answer (score 0):

In Your page "Manage Role",In Your Page load, Check that user info is available or not in the session.
and When you Click on log out button,First Remove User Information from Session and then Redirect it Login Page.

Answer (score 0):

First Remove All Session on logout button click event

```
 Session.Abandon();
    Session["SessionName"] = null;
    Session.Clear();
```

Then Write Code in Global.asax File

```
  Void Application_Error(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
         Response.Redirect("LogIn.aspx");
         or
         Server.Transfer("LogIn.aspx");
    }
```